# Fixed Header only on one page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a fixed navigation(header on the homepage. I am using wordpress therefore this fixed header is in the header.php I do not want the fixed header to also work on the other pages. How can I do that:

This is the style I am applying:

```
#header, #footer{
        position:fixed;
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        background: #05556d;
        z-index:9;
        text-align:center;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    #header{
        top:0px;
    }
    #footer{
        bottom:0px;
        padding:10px 0px;
        font-size:12px;
    }
```

What Can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the classes added on the body element. Multiple classes are there and differ with the template used, the current page etc caetera.

Use one of these to condition the `position` css property on your header.

```
#header, #footer{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #05556d;
    text-align:center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
#footer{
    padding:10px 0px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.homeClass #header, .homeClass #footer{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9;
}
.homeClass #header{
    top:0px;
}
.homeClass #footer{
    bottom:0px;
}
```

If you can't see a different class you can add one conditionnaly in functions.php:

```
add_filter('body_class','custom_body_class');

function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if(YOUR_ISHOMEPAGE_CONDITION) $classes[] = 'homeClass';
    return $classes;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Looking at the staging version I see you theme adds no class to the body whatsoever. Look at `header.php` and find the opening `body` tag. If it has no `class` attribute, then add

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

**Also**

The code in `page-js.js` invokes the jQuery fullPage plugin on every page. You should edit it so it checks the body class before calling fullPage like so:

```
if(!$('body').hasClass('home')){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({...});
}
```

Comment: YOUR_ISHOMEPAGE_CONDITION likely being `is_front_page()`

Comment: Would you be able to investigate further if I provide you a link of this ?

Comment: @ArmelLarcier I am uploading the system onto a test server rather than localhost. I will provide the link very soon so It will make an easier experience

Comment: @ArmelLarcier this a URL where you can see a live version of this: http://testing.rcb.com.mt/ as you can see in the second page of "Product Features" one cannot scroll

Comment: @ArmelLarcier lets continue this discussion in chat

Comment: Took a bit of investigating, but we got it in the end.  Looks like a good jQuery solution too. :)

Answer (score 2):

### With CSS

The body class should be `.home` on the home page. So you can make the header fixed on the home page and not the other pages by prepending `.home` to your styles:

```
.home #header, .home #footer{
    position:fixed;
    ...
}
```

Or as @Armel answered, perhaps the class differs depending on the template/theme.  You should be able to look into it with a browser developer tool and replace `.home` with whatever class it ends up being.

Might need to do the opposite and declare that all other #header and #footer elements are set to `position: static`, and it might be required to declare that it's important to override other styles: `position: static !important`.

### With WordPress PHP function

Alternatively, you could make your own class in header.php by using WordPress's [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) function.  Add a class or even just add the styling conditionally.

Comment: I am thinking actually the problem isn't coming from the css. I am using this library  https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master and I think it is applying it to the whole pages

Comment: Ah. Plugins could be more tricky. @user3492795.
If you're adding the javascript to a template file, just add it conditionally using the is_front_page function I mention in my answer.

Comment: I can't see a reason why unless the plugin adds inline styles, in which case... it sucks ;-)

Comment: Perhaps the js is being added to each page, overriding style definitions with inline styles @ArmelLarcier.  Try adding the javascript conditionally.

Comment: Would you be able to investigate further if I provide you a link of this ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to bed. :)  I'm sure you'll solve it.  @ArmelLarcier's got a pretty well detailed answer.  Only thing he might be missing is putting `position: static !important;` on the #header, #footer selectors.

Comment: don't advise him adding `!important` statements man! It will make maintaining the code a pain and it won't override inline styles anyway.

Comment: `!important` statements can be messy, and are not well-advised, but manipulating styles with javascript is messier, and trying to override that javascript conditionally could be best solved with them.  Also, I'm pretty sure they do override inline styles. http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: Where did you add the fullpage.js scripts? @user3492795

Comment: That is added in the header.php file which I am also calling in the other pages

Comment: The style you're looking to override is `overflow`: `html, body { overflow: auto !important; }` would work if you only put it in the is_front_page() condition;

Comment: Why are you calling them in the other pages if you only want it on the front page? @user3492795  That's the problem!